# How do get values from JSON array that uses a number as indentifier in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse JSON that is a response from the Web of Trust API. Problem is the API returns JSON that uses integers as identifiers and I'm having a hard time getting the values I want. I'm using `org.json:json`

Heres an example of what the JSON looks like:

```
{ 
    "google.com": { 
        "target": "google.com", 
        "0": [ 94, 73 ],
        "1": [ 94, 73 ],
        "2": [ 94, 73 ],
        "4": [ 93, 66 ],
        "categories": { 
             "501": 99, 
             "301": 43 
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to get the values from "0" and "4".

Heres the Java code I'm using to parse it:

```
package eclipseurlplugin.handlers;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class JsonTest {

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }

      public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          String jsonText = readAll(rd);
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
          return json;
        } finally {
          is.close();
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_link_json2?hosts=google.com/&key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        String jsonValue = json.getJSONObject("google.com").getString("0");
        System.out.println(jsonValue);      
      }
}
```

I'm trying to use code below to get the values but I get an exception. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
String jsonValue = json.getJSONObject("google.com").getString("0");
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the exception that you get?

Comment: Those aren't integers, they're strings containing digits.

Comment: **What Andy said** - ***always*** include the full text of the exception you're getting, when asking about an exception.

Comment: Sorry this was my first time asking a question on here, bit of a newbie. Will do in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IN `{"0": [1, 2]}` 0 indentifier have integer array so just get Json array like below :

```
JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) json.getJSONObject("google.com").getJSONArray("0");
```

Comment: You can't cast a `java.lang.String` to a `org.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: Oh.. sorry jsonObject.getJSONArray("0")  @Andy Turner

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access a list as a String. So:

```
jsonObj.getString("0")
```

would work for

```
{"0": "94, 73"}
```

but not for

```
{"0": [94, 73]}
```

You'd need to use `jsonObj.getJSONObject("0")` to get that list.